# take all nodes of one type when i parse

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm creating a parser and I use the expression `//html/body//div[@id='bodyContent']/s[1]` to take the first node with tag `<p>`.

But if I have to take all nodes, what expression should I write?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to extract all `<p>` tags within div with id `bodyContent`?

`//html/body//div[@id='bodyContent']//p`

or just all `<p>` tags?

`//p`

For instance, [jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) is a good library for xpath. You can use e.g.,

```
List<Node> nodes = new DOMXPath("//p").selectNodes(document);
for (Node node : nodes) {
    // do something with the matched nodes
    node.getValue();
}
```

Comment: What `xpath` library are you using? When you've gathered the nodes, e.g., `List<Node> nodles = executeXpath()` you can extract the information from the corresponding `Node` object.

Comment: i do in this way: XPathFactory xpathf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
String xexpr = "//html/body//div[@id='bodyContent']//p";XPath xpath = xpathf.newXPath();
XPathExpression xpathe = xpath.compile(xexpr);
s = xpathe.evaluate(docXML); but in this string s i obtain only all the nodes p and not the content! i'm not very practice in this.

Comment: See my edit, jaxen is a great library and far easier to use. Alternatively you can achieve the same using `NodeList list = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expr, item, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

Comment: ok thanks but the output isn't what i want but it's my fault. i have to take the plain text of an article of wikipedia in which the word i search has more than one definitions like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range. each definition has tag <li> but this tag it's in <ul> tag. how can i take all the plain text? i try with only the body but i obtain unwanted text. please help me

Comment: Why don't you try a xpath which extracts all `li` tags, e.g., `//li`. Then from the response `NodeList` you can easily extract the contents as illustrated in my example.